# can "He has to come back" mean "He will surely come back"?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

Wikipidia says, "The modal must expresses obligation or necessity: You must use this form; We must try to escape. It can also express a confident assumption (the epistemic rather than deontic use), such as in It must be here somewhere".

Then, isn't it true that "He must come back" can both mean "He has to come back" and "He will surely come back" ?

Comment: Note that many/most native speakers would pronounce the verb as ***hass*** (as well as place heavy stress on the word) in constructions like *He has to come.* Also note that both ***must*** and ***to have to*** can be "ambiguous" as to whether it''s the speaker and/or the person referred to who feels "under a compulsion" to do something. So *He has to win* might mean *It's desperately important to me that he wins, because I placed a large bet on him*. But it might mean *He's very competitive, and can't bear losing* (even if the speaker doesn't care one way or the other).

Comment: Thus, if you assume *He has to come back* means *He will surely come back*, you're looking at things from the *speaker's* perspective (the speaker is sure the other person *will* return, for whatever reason, and this is "necessary" *for the speaker*). But it could equally be used in contexts where it's the other person who will be compelled to return (speaker knows this to be the case, but doesn't necessarily care anyway).

Comment: I don't find the epistemic sense natural with future meaning. _He must have come back_ is clearly epistemic: "I conclude that he has come back". But _He must come back_ and _he has to come back_ are only deontic for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of conveying a clearer picture, let's give a name to the guy - Tom.

"Tom must come back" also means "Tom has to come back".

However, "Tom will surely come back" does not mean either of those, because this sentence signifies the speaker knowing Tom's will (by choice), or lack thereof (by force).